# Java Thread Interrupted Flag Gets Cleared

Tags: java, multithreading

I was experimenting with interrupts in java and observed that if i interrupt a thread and do not reset it's interrupt status when the thread state changed from RUNNABLE to TERMINATED interrupted variable gets reset (interrupted becomes false)

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        t1 t1 = new t1();
        t1.start();

        Thread.sleep(10);
        t1.interrupt();
        System.out.println("t1.isInterrupted: " + t1.isInterrupted() + " t1.state: " + t1.getState());
        Thread.sleep(20);
        System.out.println("t1.isInterrupted: " + t1.isInterrupted() + " t1.state: " + t1.getState());

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + exc);
    }

}
```

}

**t1.java**

```
public class t1 extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        System.out.println("Processing");
    }

    System.out.println("Execution completed - interrupt status: " + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
}
```

}

**Output of Main.java (Centos 7 64 bit, Java 1.8.0_66-b17)**

- Processing
  Processing
  Processing
  **t1.isInterrupted: true** t1.state: RUNNABLE
  Execution completed - **interrupt status: true**
  **t1.isInterrupted: false** t1.state: TERMINATED

My question is who or what sets this flag back to false and why ? Thread class has a private exit method that sets some internal variables to null but i couldnt find anything that resets interrupted flag. If anyone can shed some light on the issue i will be grateful ...

PS: here is a link to [GIST](https://gist.github.com/rozaydin/e2de16e0251976c8163e60b5110f0033)

Comment: "... who or what sets this flag back to false and why?" Why do you care? Someone made an implementation decision, so this is what it is.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: The thread is no longer alive, and so interrupted status will be false.

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).  It's very confusing to see a class and variable name being exactly the same. Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is who or what sets this flag back to false and why ?

This is the known behavior when the thread terminates.  Because it is no longer running, the interrupt state is false.  The interrupt state is true right before the thread terminates but is set to false once it has completed.

To quote the [`Thread.isInterrupted()` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted()):

> A thread interruption ignored because a thread was not alive at the time of the interrupt will be reflected by this method returning false.